# Internal storage screenshot saver

Tags: android

I want to save a screenshot in the internal storage on Android.I managed to save it on the external storage but how it is possible to modify this code in order to save it on the internal storage?

```
            if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()))
            {
                File sdCard=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File directory=new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/DCIM"+"/Camera");
                directory.mkdirs();
                String filename="screenshot"+i+".jpg";
                File yourFile=new File(directory,filename);
                while(yourFile.exists())
                {
                    i++;
                    filename="screenshot"+i+".jpg";
                    yourFile = new File(directory, filename);

                }
                if(!yourFile.exists())
                {
                    if(directory.canWrite())
                    {
                                   try {
                                       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(yourFile,true);
                                   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90,out);
                                   out.flush();
                                   out.close();
                                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File exported to /sdcard/Tutorial_ScreenShot/screenshot" + i + ".jpg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                       i++;
                                   }
                                   catch (IOException e)
                                   {
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                                   }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SD Card not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: But how can save programatically without change the settings of the phone.I cant figure it out.Make a printscreen(which i know to do) save it on the internal storage without any modificaton at the system settings?

Comment: @funkystein no, it is not a setting. You are confusing primary and secondary external storage.

Comment: To use the internal storage, remove everything related to external storage including the manifest permission if it is not otherwise needed.  Next call the getFilesDir() method of your activity or other valid Context and place your files there.  Note that internal storage files are by default private to their owning application.